# PHP: preg_replace file path

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm stuggeling with this regular expression:

```
preg_replace('/\/[\s\S]+?_/', '/', $currentFile)
```

It changes this: 
`/public_html/ftp/Products/1010_Air+Cooled+Condenser/productsheet_Rotary+Drum+Dryer+BR.pdf`

To this: `html/Air+Cooled+Condenser/Rotary+Drum+Dryer+BR.pdf`

Expected result:
`/public_html/ftp/Products/Air+Cooled+Condenser/Rotary+Drum+Dryer+BR.pdf`

`"/productsheet_"` could also be `"/fish-cb_"` or `"/appeltaartenbakker_"`

`"/1010_"` is always a number with this length.

Comment: Does it mean you do not want to match that pattern at the start of the string? Try [`(?!^)\/[^\/]+_`](https://regex101.com/r/RjSh9E/1). Or `(?!^)\/[^_\/]+_` if you only need to remove the part after a `/` and before the first `_` in that subpart.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew could you explain what you just did there? It works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for

```
'~(?!^)/[^/]+_~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RjSh9E/1). If you need to make it stop before the first `_`, add the underscore to the `[...]`: `'~(?!^)/[^_/]+_~'`.

**Details**

- `(?!^)` - not at the start of the string
- `/` - a `/` char (no need to escape as I am using `~` as a regex delimiter char)
- `[^/]+` - 1 or more chars other than `/`
- `_` - a `_` char.

[PHP demo:](https://ideone.com/Fsdyja)

```
$str = '/public_html/ftp/Products/1010_Air+Cooled+Condenser/productsheet_Rotary+Drum+Dryer+BR.pdf';
$result = preg_replace('~(?!^)/[^/]+_~', '/', $str);
echo $result; // => /public_html/ftp/Products/Air+Cooled+Condenser/Rotary+Drum+Dryer+BR.pdf
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how well formed those file paths are you could try:

```
preg_replace('/[0-9]{4}_(.+\/).+_/','\1',$currentFile)
```

Which I tested in php 7.0.3 and in vim with:

```
/public_html/ftp/Products/1010_Air+Cooled+Condenser/productsheet_Rotary+Drum+Dryer+BR.pdf
/public_html/ftp/Products/1020_Air+Cooled+Condenser/fish-cb_Rotary+Drum+Dryer+BR.pdf
/public_html/ftp/Products/1030_Air+Cooled+Condenser/appeltaartenbakker_Rotary+Drum+Dryer+BR.pdf
```

Using this command and very magic mode `\v`:

```
:%s/\v[0-9]{4}_(.+\/).+_/\1/g
/public_html/ftp/Products/Air+Cooled+Condenser/Rotary+Drum+Dryer+BR.pdf
/public_html/ftp/Products/Air+Cooled+Condenser/Rotary+Drum+Dryer+BR.pdf
/public_html/ftp/Products/Air+Cooled+Condenser/Rotary+Drum+Dryer+BR.pdf
```

Comment: I meant that `"/productsheet_"` could be any string.

Comment: Updated to match any string.